# How can I reset my Android layout back to default state?

Tags: android

I am writing a game which uses several Text Views that will be moved around the the screen. If the user presses a restart button, is there an easy way to restore the layout back to default using the content XML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recreate the view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
```

You may also need to remove the view that was created originally...  and you'll obviously need to re-look-up any widgets you are storing pointers to (via `findViewById`).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I could have stored everything in arrays but I thought the content XML file probably stays static and would be much more efficient to restore from using an API call. I spent an hour on Google trying to find this without luck.

Comment: If i do this, then the clicks are not working anymore

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS you need to re-lookup your widgets and reregister handlers.